# create some buttons after dataTable rendering

Tags: jquery, datatable

creating some buttons in datatable footer, but when searching or click on sorting arrow buttons disappear.
[image]

```
$(".dataTables_info").empty(); // DataTable Footer class
   var refresh = $('<a id="refresh" href="javascript:void(0)"> <i class="mdi mdi-refresh"></i></a>');
   var add = $('<a id="add" href="javascript:void(0)"> <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i></a>').css("margin-left","4px",
      "text-decoration","none");

   var erase = $('<a id="erase" href="javascript:void(0)"> <i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a>').css("margin-left","4px","text-decoration","none");

   $(".dataTables_info").append([refresh,add,erase])
```

How to fix it after rendering datatable?